# In UFT, what value does an empty Data Cell hold? Is it an empty string or null?

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

In UFT, you have the possibility to use 'Data' which is essentially an excel sheet which can be used to drive tests.

My question is, if one of these cells is blank, is its value an empty string or is it null?  Either way I can get around it but I'm curious so I can help map the rest of the problem out in my head.

Comment: Was there really a need to amend the question?  All you did was remove further information that offered clarity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, **there is no `data` function I know of**. You probably are referring to the `DataTable.Value` method instead.

**`DataTable.Value` should always return the empty string for empty cells.**

As to the question about performance -- no, **I would not expect a bottleneck here**. And even if -- optimizing for a performance problem you don´t yet face is called premature optimization. Don´t do that. Today´s CPUs are too fast for you to sense the difference between `IsEmpty`, `IsNull`, or checking for empty string equality. 
There usually are other operations that consume much more runtime, and are well more worth optimizing.

The `Null` value and the `IsNull` function are seldomly used in VBScript, or, for that matter, QTP/UFT.

You can think of `Empty` and `IsEmpty` existing for variables that have never received a value (or that explicitely received `Empty`).

In contrast to that, `Nothing` is useful for initializing a variable to an `Empty`-like value if that variable is to hold an object reference later, because `Is Nothing` returns a valid value for such variable in both cases (case 1: uninitialized, i.e. initialized to `Nothing`, and case 2: assigned to a valid object instance), while `Is Nothing` would fail if the variable contains `Empty` (RTE: "object required"). Similarily, leaving unitialized object reference variables initialized to `Empty` (think about that, because that´s what happens!) and later assigning that variable to another variable using `Set` (as you have to because it possibly holds an object reference in the non-empty case) will fail if the contained value is `Empty` (you´d need to use a normal assignment with `=` and without `Set`) while it will succeed (i.e. does not RTE) if it contains `Nothing` (or an object reference).

And yes, this all being said, it is quite counterintuitive that `DataTable.Value` returns an empty string for an empty cell, and *not* the `Empty` value.

Adding to the confusion potential, `Empty = ""` always returns `true`, which might not be what one would expect, because hey! an empty string value is by definition a string value, just like a non-empty string, so why should it be considered to be equal to `Empty`? But it is, because to do the comparison, `Empty` is converted to a string, and `CStr (Empty)` is the empty string, which of course is "".

Comment: `IsEmpty("")` returns `False` (because the literal value "" is **not** an unitialized variable); there are no pointers in VBScript, `Null` is a specific **value** that indicates 'initialized but not valid'.

Comment: Updated. And: Sure VBScript does not have pointers. What I mean is that the null value is guaranteed to be equal to the null pointer values that you might receive (as a Variant) from external APIs. Is that right or wrong?

Comment: Wrong - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc237865.aspx: a VT_NULL variant is not a VT_PTR variant containing 0. And: Empty evaluates to 0 in numerical context.

Comment: Thank you, you answered the question and gave me a lot more useful information around the topic that I didn't know about.

Comment: While premature optimization may be what I'm concerned about, I really do not believe this to be a bad approach.  UFT runs like a dog at the best of times so small wins are exactly what we want in every single test, otherwise we will have a performance problem and going back to address those performance issues would be painful to say the least.

Comment: This is exactly what not to do, sorry. UFT will not run faster if you optimize the last nanosecond out of sub-microsecond operations that happen once or twice a second. Better analyze the bottleneck, and optimize that. For example, if you save your tests in QC, there are numerous things you can do to address that bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

Finally RDP actually worked, think I have an answer to this!

I found the following which seems to describe the same issue that I was running into: http://www.sqaforums.com/forums/hp-unified-functional-testing-uft-mercury-quicktest-pro-qtp/150547-isempty-isnull-not-returning-true-blank-cells-local-datasheet.html

Essentially isNull, isEmpty, checking against null wasn't working on occasion.  Based on the forum post and what I've just tested with checking the variable <> "" seems the best approach.

However, is there a performance hit with this?